# Retrieve word weigth or TF_IDF in python

Tags: python, tf-idf

I have a labeled data set of tweets, I want to retrieve each word and the corresponding weight or TF_IDF in Python

Comment: Hello, you should offer a minimal code example of what you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does your data look like? You need to provide more information in order for us to understand your request